# DNS with Raspberry as Wi-FI AP for local users

Tags: apache-httpd, dns

I have a website running on Apache. When users connect to the Raspberry AP, they can access to the website using the Raspberry's IP.

But  what I want to do is type an speific direction (like "Mywebsite.com"), and this will redirect me to the Raspberry's IP.

I've used hostapd and dnsmasq, but I don´t know how to configure the last one to do this.

Comment: So, do you plan to setup a closed loop network (no internet) with a Raspi AP and nodes connected to that?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to configure [dnsmasq correctly](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html), add the [A records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) [private class IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) only, I denoted three methods for resolving hosts (without using upstream servers for sure), example :

**NOTE: Assume 192.168.1.1 is the dnsmasq IPv4 listen address for the DNS server**

You must find associated parameters for choose a method how to serve the dns response What you did not specify correctly in your question.(upstream server ? -S, --local, --server ?) , the best choice is to read the dnsmasq configuration file.

```
listen-address=192.168.1.1
no-resolv # tell dnsmasq don't read the /etc/resolv.conf dns server system file.
no-hosts # tell dnsmasq don't read /etc/hostname system file.
log-queries # log the dns queries
log-facility=/tmp/dnsmasq.queries.txt #log the queries into specified file
```

### **1)** Using address=/domain/ipaddr' in dnsmasq configuration file:

```
# A records (can probably be simplified in one line if the same server is used)
address=/myvhost1.org/192.168.1.1/
address=/myvhost2.org/192.168.1.1/
address=/myvhost3.org/192.168.1.1/
```

### **2)** Using your own host file in dnsmasq configuration file:

```
addn-hosts=/tmp/myhosts.conf
```

and create a file **/tmp/myhosts.conf** containing :

```
192.168.1.1  myvhost1.org
192.168.1.1  myvhost2.org
192.168.1.1  myvhost3.org
```

### **3)** Using the Linux /etc/hostname file:

If you comment **no-hosts** dnsmasq parameter , then the daemon read **/etc/hostname** file, then you can add each records into this hostname file :

```
192.168.1.1   myvhost1.org 
192.168.1.1   myvhost2.org 
192.168.1.1   myvhost3.org
```

Finally associate each hostnames in your apache2 vhosts conf files:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
    ServerName myvhost1.org
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain/myvhost1"
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
    ServerName myvhost2.org
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain/myvhost2"
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:80>
    ServerName myvhost3.org
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain/myvhost3"
    ...
</VirtualHost>
....
```

And **enable ALL vhosts and restart ALL daemons**.

**Note** that the dns server for the client is normally specified in the dhcp configuration, if you use dnsmasq as the dhcp server you must specify the necessary dhcp option:

```
dhcp-option=6,192.168.1.1
```

where 192.168.1.1 is always your dns server (dnsmasq) listen address or else configure manually the client dns.

### Somes steps:

```
# 192.168.1.1 is the dnsmasq IPv4 listen address for the DNS server , else adapting... 
~$ ip a add 192.168.1.1/24 dev wlan0
~$ ip a #ensure your interface have the dns server correct IPv4    

# HTTP
~$ sudo a2ensite myvhost1.conf
~$ sudo a2ensite myvhost2.conf
~$ sudo a2ensite myvhost3.conf     
~$ sudo systemctl reload apache2.service

# DNS
~$ sudo systemctl reload dnsmasq.service
~$ nslookup myvhost1.org 192.168.1.1  # Must return a correct response : 192.168.1.1
~$ dig myvhost1.org @192.168.1.1  # Must return a correct response : 192.168.1.1
~$ sudo cat /tmp/dnsmasq.queries.txt
~$ sudo cat /etc/hostname
~$ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Global
~$ sudo journalctl
~$ ss -ln #show listening addr and port
...
```

**Be careful because here I use the temporary folder /tmp for the development and it is emptied at each restart by Linux so you will lose your log files or configuration. Adapt according to your needs. Also, I do not mean here any privilege or right on the folders and files, so be sure to do the necessary on this side.**

Comment: Much taken effort but where does this answer a question about **Raspberry Pi**? I haven't found any word about Raspberry Pi.

Comment: apache2 and dnsmasq run on raspberry , no ? he say: "I have a website running on apache"... I do not understand the meaning of your remark.

Comment: Apache2 and dnsmasq run on many computer including Raspberry Pi. There are many other programs are running on Raspberry Pi. But only that they are running but having general problems doesn't say that's a specific problem for Raspberry Pi. Please have a look at our policies at [How do I write a good answer?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). There you will find "*..avoid trying to answer questions which... are not about raspberry pi as [defined in the help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*".

Comment: @Ingo,  I see, yes is not really related to the raspberry-pi, exact...

Comment: I delete this answer...

Comment: No, let it there. It's much effort and it doesn't hurt...

Comment: @Ingo, Okay, so I'm listening to you. Sorry I'll be more careful now.

Answer (score 0):

On the Raspi AP,

- Setup a DNS server. I prefer bind. `sudo apt-get install bind9`
- Create a zone for your site `mywebsite.com`
- Create an `A record` such as `www` (resolving the raspi LAN IP) for your site.

It will be hard for you to complete the last 2 steps via command line. I suggest you to use a GUI for bind. [Here](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/bindweb.htm), there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the Pi with `hostname.local` - default hostname is raspberrypi.

Each device should have a unique hostname.